# Server firewall is blocking the Web3.js connection in NODE

Tags: web3js, nodejs, firewalls

My Centos server has running the "ConfigServer Security & Firewall" and its blocking the Web3.js connection with Ethereum node. The functions calls returns: "Error: Invalid JSON RPC response:"

Any idea how could I avoid it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved opening the TCP OUT 30303 (Ethereum listeners) and 8545 (JSON-RPC) ports.